# React native web scrollView horizontal scroll with mouse

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-web

Using react-native-web, I have a scrollView with content much wider than the screen. Using 'horizontal' I can scroll along the x-Axis as expected, however only with the touchpad of my laptop. Mouse wheel scrolling doesn't do anything since the wheel apparenlt only scrolls vertically and not horizontally.
I have been looking for a while but cannot find any way to do horizontal scrolling with the mouse wheel.
Any help with this would be greatly appriciated!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By default, the user needs to hold `Shift + Scrolling Mouse Wheel` to scroll horizontally.

**Edit**: This issue can be solved via jQuery but requires you to hide the vertical bar with CSS "overflow-y: hidden". You will need to download [jQuery.js](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js) and [jQuery-mousewhee.min.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/blob/main/jquery.mousewheel.min.js) and include them in your html.

After you download the files, include the scripts below in your code.

```
<script scr="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script scr="jquery-mousewhee.min.js"></script>
```

Then include in your body's CSS (or any div that you want to scroll horizontally)

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Finally, add in the custom script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Done**.

Note: You will need to mess around with the code if you want to include the vertical bar back.

Comment: Yes, that does result in scrolling, but my users are not going to know that they need to press shift for scrolling since it's not very intuitive to do here. Is there any way to achieve the scrolling without the need for pressing shift?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I just provided the new solution.

Comment: I have the vertical bar hidden anyway so this is perfect for me. Thank you very much for your help, this solves it!

Comment: How can this be an accepted answer ? This involve jQuery on top of react-native

Comment: jQuery is a terrible solution here